# PHP regex - how to uniqely match domains?

Tags: php, regex

I have two possible URL-s in my web app.

1. www.domain.com
2. www.user.domain.com

Now I need two php regexs that will match each URL uniquely.

I wrote two regexs:

```
1. (www\.)?(domain)(\.)(com)
2. (www\.)?([a-z]+)(\.)(domain)(\.)(com)
```

The first one will match first URL.
The second one will match second URL but it will match first URL too. Thats the problem.

How to write regex to match each of these URLs uniqely?

Here is link to rubular premalink so you can see whats my problem.
LINK: [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/QWyANvtXJK)

Comment: Do both have optional `www`?  Would `user.domain.com` work as well?

Comment: Why not split on `.` and see if one of the resulting arrays is contained in the other?

Comment: @d3v3us Yes, both should work with or without www. So (www\.)? at the beginning should be there, I think. But yes they must have optional www.

Comment: @Jack Maney - Im dont really understand. Im still fresh with regexs. You meen split URL with preg_split(/\./); ?

Comment: Can you show some code as to why you can't have number 2 work on both?  I suspect, if you want to do something different based on which one it is, then ordering your conditionals correctly, and using an `else` would work.

Comment: @d3v3us - whoowhoo :S I didnt see that one coming. I gues I can deal with that one, limit users so they cant use www as username. That would be easy if I could came up with the right regex.

Comment: @d3v3us Well, each URL has different controller. And I need to have URL-s joust like that. I cant take controller name from the URL like in any other MVC framework, www.domain.com/controller/method/params/.../ . I had to came up with a way to override this and to use different controller for both of them. Now I only need a way to uniqely match them so I can call different controller for each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^(((www\.)([a-z]+))|(?!(www\.))([a-z]+))(\.)(domain)(\.)(com)$
```

Comment: This will work, though it is a little ugly for what you are trying to do and starts to get away from the power of using regular expressions.  At the point I had something like this, I would evaluate doing somthing like @Jack suggested in the comments to the question, and split the domain and check its parts.

Comment: This regex uses 10 groups!